# evaluating or making a function javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

So, it's my first time here, hello!

I'm working in a "math calculator" just for fun and I was thinking about using `eval("...")` or `(x => ...)` to define a function, viewing which one is faster in all major browsers...

example:
i have a function:

```
function f(x){ return x+1; }
```

I can make `eval(x+1)`(getting x in a for loop) or making `var f = (x => x+1)` and making `f(i)`(being i in a for loop)

What can I do?

Comment: Try looking at `CoffeeScript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly but the following JSPerf contrasts the difference between eval and function.

It compares the two following pieces of code:

```
(function() {
  eval(strCode);
})();
```

As opposed to a new function

```
(function() {
  (new Function(strCode))();
})();
```

Eval is inferior I believe due to an additional interpreter layer.

http://jsperf.com/eval-methods